# How to get a list of tuple from freqDist in nltk

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, nltk, word-count

I have a dataframe with two column `id` and `text`

I want to add a new column that contains word count for the text per row.

I create a userdefinedFunction in which i implement `word_tokenizer` and `freqDict` from `nltk`

```
word = f.udf(lambda token: word_count)

def word_count(token):
    freq_dict = nltk.probability.FreqDist(token)
    return [(word, freq) for word, freq in freq_dict.most_common()]

df = df.withColumn('wordcount',word(nltk.word_tokenize(df['text']))
```

After tokenizer i call `word_count` and hope to get a list of tuple with word and its freq. but instead in get this in the column

```
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@9b4c4d5, [Ljava.lang.Object;@6a5d7d39, ...
```

Comment: I believe the use of `nltk.word_tokenize` is the issue here, because you are using it on the whole column, not per row. Could you please try with the `nltk.word_tokenize` within the `word_count` udf, so that word count takes a text as input, tokenizes it and returns the most common words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the return type for the UDF.
Define a schema like this

```
schema = ArrayType(StructType([StructField("word",StringType(), True), StructField("freq",LongType(), True)]))
```

and change the udf to

```
f.udf(word_count, schema)
```